# Reading a persistent object's variable prevents it from being added to an object later

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to make a new object Session and persist it to the database. It has a persistent variable of object User. I query the DB for the user I want to add to the session. If the user's password doesn't match "hello" (for now obviously), stop. If it does, make a new session, set the regular variables and add sOwner (just set Session's User variable). Like this, the code works but doesn't check the password...

```
try {
    Query u = pm.newQuery(User.class); //Query for user
    u.setFilter("email == eaddr");
    u.declareImports("import java.lang.String");
    u.declareParameters("String eaddr");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> res = (List<User>)u.execute(email);
    sOwner = res.get(0);
    //if (!sOwner.getPassword().equals("hello")) {  // comment out
    //throw new Exception("password not correct");  // these three lines
    //}                                 // and it works
    sNew = new Session();
    sNew.setUser(sOwner);
    sNew.setIpAddr(ipAddr);
    sNew.setStartedOn(new Date());
    sNew.setToken(token);
    pm.makePersistent(sNew);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

but without the if statement commented out, the final committing of the changes has this error:

```
2385571 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" (id="com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session:381") is having the value in field "startedOn" replaced by a SCO wrapper
2385571 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Native  - INSERT INTO `SESSION` (`TOKEN`,`STARTEDON`,`USERAGENT`,`IPADDR`,`USER_ID_OID`,`ID`) VALUES (<'90a9d90f325c3b'>,<2011-02-24 19:12:15.595>,<null>,<'127.0.0.5'>,<21>,<381>)
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist  - Execution Time = 1 ms (number of rows = 1)
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Insert of object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" is calling insertPostProcessing for field "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session.user"
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Insert of object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" is calling insertPostProcessing for field "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session.transaction"
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve  - Closing PreparedStatement org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@2ac7bf18
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Insert of object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" is calling postInsert for field "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session.user"
2385572 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Insert of object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" is calling postInsert for field "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session.transaction"
2385584 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Object "com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce" field "transaction" is replaced by a SCO wrapper of type "org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.List" [cache-values=true, lazy-loading=true, queued-operations=false, allow-nulls=true]
2385585 [btpool0-0] DEBUG com.yachtcloser.server.DispatchServlet  - Response Sent:{"cmds":[{"response":"Session 381 created by user 0"}]}
2385585 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - ObjectManager internalFlush() process started - 1 dirty objects
2385585 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - ObjectManager internalFlush() process finished
2385589 [btpool0-0] ERROR DataNucleus.Persistence  - java.lang.NullPointerException
2385590 [btpool0-0] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Disconnecting com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce from StateManager[pc=com.yachtcloser.server.om.Session@14446bce, lifecycle=P_NEW]
```

Here's the stack trace of the NPE I think:

```
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatementHelper.selectMemberOfSourceInStatement(SQLStatementHelper.java:723)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.processMembersOfClass(FetchRequest.java:478)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.<init>(FetchRequest.java:166)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.getFetchRequest(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:329)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.fetchObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:306)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2028)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadUnloadedFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1685)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.runReachability(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3295)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performReachabilityAtCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3415)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3268)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl$2.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:324)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:394)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:279)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:90)
    at com.yachtcloser.server.UserContext.finishRequest(UserContext.java:181)
    at com.yachtcloser.server.DispatchServlet.doPost(DispatchServlet.java:185)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.yachtcloser.server.DispatchServlet.service(DispatchServlet.java:55)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

I tried detaching a copy, and comparing that password, then adding the original query result 
to the session, that didn't work either.  Here's the important part of Session which I can't edit by the way:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Session  implements Comparable<Session> {

    @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
  private long id;

  @Persistent
  private User user;
```

datanucleus-core-2.2.2.jar, datanucleus-connectionpool-2.0.3.jar, datanucleus-googlecollections-2.2.0-release.jar, datanucleus-jdo-query-2.2.1.jar, datanucleus-rdbms-2.2.2.jar, jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar, datanucleus-enhancer-2.1.3.jar, asm-3.3.1.jar   those are the jar files I see

Comment: You get an NPE, but don't quote the stack trace, so we can't see where it comes from - that would be the point to start from. Also state the version of software being used, and the datastore being used

Comment: MySql 5.1 and 10.10 Ubuntu, developing in Eclipse.  I added what I believe is the stack trace you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

A query generates SQL. That is printed in the DataNucleus log. Consequently you ought to check the SQL generated for your query. The stack trace is created from tx.commit() yet you don't mention such a call.

You don't say the version of DataNucleus in use ... of each plugin jar.

Comment: I added the jar filenames; the stack trace I included is the same as when I stack traced the <persistencemanagerinstance>.currentTransaction.commit();   commit is referenced at line 14 about I believe  "at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:279)"    all I know is that it commits after the try/catch that is posted first completes and the function it's in returns.

Comment: and the SQL ? The only way to show something is demonstrate it in a simple testcase.

Comment: My boss found the issue, a datanucleus option for strict persistence checking or precommitting or something, now it works fine. Thanks for the effort and sorry I couldn't give the information you needed, I'm new to this :/